# Make text appear briefly in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, text

I am trying to make text appear briefly before it disappears. It would be along the lines of
1) Set color to black
2) wait x amount of seconds
3) set color to background color

The method I call is *repaint()*, which then calls *paintComponent(Graphics painter)*. *repaint()* is called only if I press the space-bar.

I thought of trying `repaint();Thread.sleep(1000);repaint();` (I do catch the Interrupt exception, just not shown), but it only calls *paintComponent* once per space-bar .

Is there an easy way to do this or is this something that is a bit challenging?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the repainting of the text.

Also, I would just use a JLabel to display the text. Then you just use the setText(...) method to change the text as you wish and the component will repaint itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the paint method in your panel and make it implement `Runnable` so that you can turn off the text after a few seconds. Here is some sample code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.Exception;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;   


class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

 private final static String TEXT = "HELLO WORLD";
 private boolean on = true;

 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);

  if(on){
   g.drawString(TEXT, 20, 20);
  }

 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  for(int i = 0 ; i< 2 ; i++){
   paintImmediately(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
   try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   on = false;
  }
 }
}

public class App {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  final MyPanel p =  new MyPanel();
  f.add(p);
  f.setSize(100,100);
  f.setVisible(true);
  Thread t = new Thread(p);
  t.start();
 }
}
```

Comment: Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method.